# $n^2 \ge \Omega(n)$ Notation Proof

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Task is to prove or refute
$n^2 \ge \Omega(n)$

$n^2$ is a function, $\Omega(n)$ is a set of functions. So is this another way of saying the set of Omega functions is a lower bound on $f$?
i.e. is 
$n^2 \ge \Omega(n)$ 
equivalent to
$n^2 \in \Omega(n)$ ?

We know that n $ \in O(n^2)$
It follows then that $n^2 \in \Omega(n)$?

Or 
let $C = 1, n_0 = 1$
then
$n^2 \ge 1 \cdot f(n) = 1 \cdot n$ $\forall n_0 \ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I think you are right. $n^2 \ge \Omega(n)$ is just another way of writing $n^2 \in \Omega(n)$

So our goal is to show $n^2 \in \Omega(n)$

By definition, we need to find some $C \in \mathbb{R}^+, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ we have $n^2 \ge Cn$

Now pick $C = 1$ and $n_0 = 1$. Then we are done. So your answer is correct.

Besides, your other approach: $n \in \mathcal{O}(n^2) \implies n^2 \in \Omega(n)$ is also correct. To see that, we prove the following fact:

$$f \in \mathcal{O}(g) \iff g \in \Omega(f)$$

($\implies$)

By definition, we can find $C \in \mathbb{R}^+, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ we have $f \le C g$

So for this $C, n_0$ for all $n \ge n_0$ we have $g \ge \frac{1}{C} f$

By definition, $g \in \Omega(f)$

The proof of the other direction is similar.